# Divs are partially centred but can't get it centred dynamically

Tags: html, css

http://cathybrooks.freeiz.com/

So I have the header footer and a content container all in a container and I'm trying to get everything inside it to be centred and when the window resized have it dynamically stay centred (including pushing the portfolio display boxes to stack). I have used left/right property to position the nav and footer (the main problems) but this is not ideal as it's not centred based on the middle most element of the list and instead positions the list by the first element. How can I go about centering the header and footer based on the length of the list rather than position the first element? This should be able to work no matter how many elements I add. Thanks!

```
<div class = "container">

        <ul class = "nav">
            <li><a href = "#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href = "cv.html">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href = "contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a id = "name" href = "index.html">CATHERINEROSEART</a>

        <div id = "wrapper">

            <div id = "content">   

                <div class = "portfoliowrapper">
                    <div class = "left">
                        <a href = "#">
                            <div id = "box-1" class = "box">  
                                <img id = "image-1" src = "img/1.jpg"/>  
                                <div class = "caption fade-caption">  
                                    <h3>Piece 1</h3>  
                                    <p class = "captp">Piece 1</p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "middle">
                        <a href = "#">
                            <div id = "box-2" class = "box">  
                                <img id = "image-2" src = "img/1.jpg"/>  
                                <div class = "caption fade-caption">  
                                    <h3>Piece 2</h3>  
                                    <p class = "captp">Piece 2</p>  
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "right">
                        <a href = "#">
                            <div id = "box-2" class = "box">  
                                <img id = "image-2" src = "img/1.jpg"/>  
                                <div class = "caption fade-caption">  
                                    <h3>Piece 2</h3>  
                                    <p class = "captp">Piece 2</p>  
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>



            <div id = "footer">
                <ul class = "nav">
                    <li><a href = "#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "https://twitter.com/cathychYEAH" target = "_blank">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "https://plus.google.com/u/0/+CatherineBrooks/posts" target = "_blank">Google+</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "http://uk.linkedin.com/pub/catherine-rose-brooks/61/7/563" target = "_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "http://catherineroseart.bigcartel.com/" target = "_blank">BigCartel</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>© Catherine Brooks 2013 </p>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* nav style */

.nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 25px 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #C7C7C7;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    color: #A6A6A6;
}

/* end nav style */

/* content style */

#wrapper {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.left, .middle, .right {
    width: 31%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: left;
}

#name {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 45px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;    
}

a, #name {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333333;
}

a:visited {
    color: #333333;
}

#name {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#name:hover {
    color: #636363;
}

/* folio style */

.portfoliowrapper {  
    font: 10pt normal Arial, sans-serif;  
    height: auto;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    text-align: center;  
    width: 100%;  
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}  

.portfoliowrapper .box {  
    border: 5px solid #fff;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    height: 250px;  
    left: 0;
    right: 0; 
    margin: 5px;  
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    width: 250px;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    display: inline-block;
}  

.portfoliowrapper .box img {  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}  

.portfoliowrapper .box .caption {  
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);  
    position: absolute;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;  
    left: 0;  
}  

.portfoliowrapper .box .fade-caption, .portfoliowrapper .box .scale-caption {  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 250px;  
    height: 250px;  
    text-align: left;  
    padding: 15px;  
}  

.portfoliowrapper .box:hover .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 1;  
}    

/* end folio style */

/* footer style */

#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#footer p {
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #C7C7C7;
    font-size: 8px;
}

#footer .nav {
    bottom: 5%;
}

#footer .nav li a {
    color: #333333;
}

#footer .nav li a:hover {
    color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your elements are off-centre is because `<ul>` by default has some left padding (usually to make room for the bullet point).

Add `.nav{padding:0}` and you should be all good.

Also, note that your `.nav ul` styles aren't doing anything. In order to apply, the selector should be `ul.nav`, no space. However in this case, they are not needed and in fact would harm your layout. Just remove that block.

Comment: One would assume the most sneaky part is where there is `width: 1000px;` in the .container{}

Comment: That's irrelevant to the problem, though, because the `.nav` elements have `position:fixed` ;)

Comment: I misread the question then. I understood his entire page is off-center. Which it is if you render his code :S. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to clean it up a bit:

HTML:

```
<div class = "header">
    <ul class = "nav">
        <li><a href = "#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href = "cv.html">CV</a></li>
        <li><a href = "contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS - Body and NAV:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* nav style */
.header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}

.nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 25px 10px 25px;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #C7C7C7;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    color: #A6A6A6;
}

/* end nav style */
```

CSS - Wrapper (Didn't edit the individual picture frames etc)

```
#wrapper {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.left, .middle, .right { /*Why not just 1 class*/
    width: 31%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

CSS - Footer

```
/* footer style */

#footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
}

#footer p {
    padding: 5px; /*suggestion, since the copyright text changed from the original*/
    text-align: center;
    color: #C7C7C7;
    font-size: 8px;
}

#footer .nav li a {
    color: #333333;
}

#footer .nav li a:hover {
    color: #A6A6A6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. In terms of the .left, .middle and .right classes, I had them styled a different way to this and hadn't gotten around to tidying up!